# Phases skipped when using PrettyFaces (JSF)

Tags: jsf, phase, prettyfaces

When using PrettyFaces to map a page containing a form, all phases after Restore View are skipped and the response is rendered. Thus the form is not submitted and the model is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been caused by some missing `<dispatcher>` elements in the filters' configuration in web.xml.